# Why does Home Improvement prevent my question from being deleted if its been closed and downvoted?

Tags: support

I recently posted a question which was closed and then received several down-votes after being closed and having chosen an accepted answer. I tried to delete the question but SE doesn't allow this. So my question is, why does SE want to keep what's clearly a low quality question? And as a user, how is it fair that I'm receiving down-votes for something I have no control over?

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question in the title:

> Why does Home Improvement prevent my question from being deleted if its been closed and downvoted?

Because (apparently, by the three upvotes and the accept vote) it produced a valuable answer, which somebody took the effort/time to write. It would not be fair to them if *you* could delete your question just because you received **a few** downvotes. (Two is 'a few', not an 'assault'.) Looking at it from another way, you even gained reputation from that question (one upvote compensates for *five* downvotes).

> What do the down-voters expect me to do?

I don't know (I can't read minds), but since they all happened after you posted a comment referring to them as 'elitist mobs', one simple thing would be not to use terms like that. Decent/interesting questions that are not suitable for the site are closed, but not necessarily downvoted.

Comment: Lately we have had a lot of questions downvoted with no reason, I know I reverse these unless the question is horrible. I see questions down voted because they may violate code who knows they are asking the question because they don’t know and if the reason for the downvote there should be a comment to the downvote.